# iPhone Push Notifications Custom Sound, no Vibrate in silent mode?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

So, I have Push Notifications working fine to my app with Custom Sounds.  However, when my iPhone is in silent mode, and I send a push notification with a custom sound, the sound obviously does not play, but there is also no vibration.

If I send a push notification with a sound="chime" or something that doesn't exist like that, the iPhone's SMS notification sound plays as expected, and in silent phone, it vibrates, as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: sound="chime" is really "sound" : "chime" in the json, so it's not that I'm building the JSON wrong.

Comment: Perhaps add some of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this, I figured it out finally.

It's actually on Apple's end.  If you send out a push notification with a sound, and badge only, but no text alert, it will play the sound if your phone is not in silent mode, however it will NOT play the sound if it IS in silent mode.

Now, if you add a text alert to that notification, it plays the sound fine, even while in vibrate mode.

There may be some more testing to be done around this.  Eg: if you send custom key/value pairs does it play the sound then?  Not sure.

Comment: Can you verify what happens if you sending your own text/ and sound files...can you cause the phone to play the sound in silent mode...?
can you force the iphone to vibrate also as part of the notification with the attached sound?
can i control it? for instance decide it to be: sound, sound + vibrate, vibrate only or none..from the server side (the push initiator?)

Comment: also, is it possible to override the volume of the iphone in the notification sound? can i play a sound max volume even that the iphone volume is only half the max volume?

Comment: @Itay I don't believe you can cause a sound to play in silent mode but rather it vibrates then.  I don't believe you can force it to vibrate, basically Apple either plays the sound or vibrates, but will not vibrate if there was no text alert.  You can't control the combo of sound + vibrate from push...

Comment: @Itay No you cannot override the volume either...

In your push notification you can specify text, sound, and badge (and custom keys but that's irrelevant for this conversation).  If the phone is not in silent mode, the sound will play no matter if you send a text or badge...  If the phone IS in silent mode, the phone will only vibrate if you send a sound AND text...

Comment: @Redth - The Biggest issue our app is encountered is that it can't override the volume/mute switch on the iPhone when we try to send a push notification (with sound and text) ...It seems that Apple doesn't allow it for their own reasons.
Even with the new run in the background capability it can't receive the push notification while it is in the background...:(

Comment: @Itay indeed.  There's nothing you can do about this.  As for the backgrounded apps, well unless you are specifying your apps as one of the types that can ACTUALLY run in the background (voip, location), then your app is not actually doing anything (although you can schedule some code to keep running for up to like 10 minutes after your app is closed).  You are right, there's no way to override the volume/mute switch on the phone, that's just how it is.