# UILocalNotification sound in silent mode

Tags: ios, audio, uilocalnotification

I want play the sound of local notification even if the phone is in silent mode, i have refereed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359818/iphone-push-notifications-custom-sound-no-vibrate-in-silent-mode) for playing the push notification sound in silent mode.

I want to know, can we do the same for the `UILocalNotification` also?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not possible, the user has turned off sound and your app should respect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are Local Notifications, allowing apps to play an alarm sound at a specified time. But other than that, local notifications are of very limited usefulness to a sophisticated alarm clock app:

1. A local notification does not wake up the app unless the user
   interacts with it, giving the app no control when the alarm sounds.
2. Alert sounds have a maximum duration of 30 seconds and there is no
   way to repeat them automatically. (An app could schedule multiple
   local notifications in pre-defined time intervals to simulate a
   repeating alert, though.)
3. Local notifications cannot override the ring/silent switch or the
   device’s Do Not Disturb setting.
4. Alert sounds must be located in the app bundle. Users cannot specify
   a song from their music library as their alert.
5. Apps have no control over the volume of a local notification’s alert
   sound (for example, to slowly crank up the volume of the alarm).

Reference  Link : 
http://oleb.net/blog/2014/02/alarm-clock-apps-ios/